# Why is DC motor speed and torque direction the same, whereas in a generator it is the opposite?

Tags: electric-machine

What’s the relation between speed and torque in a DC machine. I know it’s inversely proportional but how?

Torque is nothing but twisting moment right? If torque increases then speed must be increased, but it’s wrong. Why?

Answer (score 5):

That's two separate questions. From the title:

> Why in dc motor speed and torque direction is same where as in generator is opposite?

Because the flow of mechanical power (into or out of the machine) is opposite in the two cases.

> Whats the relation between speed and torque in dc machine i know its inversely proportional but how?? Torque is nothing but twisting moment right.. if torque increases then speed must be increased but its wrong why??

Power is speed × torque. Therefore if power is constant, then the two factors must be inversely proportional. If they both increase, then the power must increase, too.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Dave’s answer...

EMF is generated with RPM thus current starts at I=V/DCR @ 0RPM when connect to voltage source or sink, defined as 0 Ohms but may be small mOhm.

A mechanical short circuit is a locked rotor as a motor or as a Gen. at an RPM that is held constant by driving motor with an external change in voltage resulting in torque that matches currents at any RPM if it were a motor with the same but opposite load torque.

It will be expected that currents reverses direction along with  torque but limited by difference between external voltage and counter EMF over loop resistance.  DC motors are rated by V/Hz of commutation or kRPM/V.